# Kubernetes: Cannot deploy a simple "Couchbase" service

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I am new to Kubernetes I am trying to mimic a behavior a bit like what I do with `docker-compose` when I serve a Couchbase database in a docker container.

```yaml
  couchbase:
    image: couchbase
    volumes:
      - ./couchbase:/opt/couchbase/var
    ports:
      - 8091-8096:8091-8096
      - 11210-11211:11210-11211
```

I managed to create a cluster in my localhost using a tool called "[kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#creating-a-cluster)"

```sh
kind create cluster --name my-cluster
kubectl config use-context my-cluster
```

Then I am trying to use that cluster to deploy a Couchbase service

I created a file named `couchbase.yaml` with the following content (I am trying to mimic what I do with my docker-compose file).

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: couchbase
  namespace: my-project
  labels:
    platform: couchbase
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      platform: couchbase
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        platform: couchbase
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: couchbase-data
        hostPath:
          # directory location on host
          path: /home/me/my-project/couchbase
          # this field is optional
          type: Directory
      containers:
      - name: couchbase
        image: couchbase
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/couchbase/var
          name: couchbase-data
```

Then I start the deployment like this:

```sh
kubectl create namespace my-project
kubectl apply -f couchbase.yaml
kubectl expose deployment -n my-project couchbase --type=LoadBalancer --port=8091
```

However my deployment never actually start:

```sh
kubectl get deployments -n my-project couchbase
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
couchbase   0/1     1            0           6m14s
```

And when I look for the logs I see this:

```sh
kubectl logs -n my-project -lplatform=couchbase --all-containers=true
Error from server (BadRequest): container "couchbase" in pod "couchbase-589f7fc4c7-th2r2" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
```

Comment: The tool kind is based on Docker images that create their own file system layer in which Kubernetes is running. So you cannot refer in your deployment to a local path on your machine because these paths are not accessible for Kubernetes. Maybe there is a trick to escape and maybe this comment helps you.

Comment: Try https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#extra-mounts . Is is what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes you were right: just to complete your answer: the error shows up when I run this command: `kubectl describe pods -n`

I could fix it by creating a new kind cluster:
`kind create cluster --config cluster.yaml`

Passing this content in cluster.yaml:

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
name: inf
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraMounts:
  - hostPath: /home/me/my-project/couchbase
    containerPath: /couchbase
```

In couchbase.yaml the path becomes `path: /couchbase` of course

Answer (score 1):

As OP mentioned in a comment, issue was solved using extra mount as explained in documentation: https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#extra-mounts

Here is OP's comment but formated so it's more readable:

---

the error shows up when I run this command:

```
kubectl describe pods -n my-project couchbase
```

I could fix it by creating a new kind cluster:

```
kind create cluster --config cluster.yaml
```

Passing this content in `cluster.yaml`:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
name: inf
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraMounts:
  - hostPath: /home/me/my-project/couchbase
    containerPath: /couchbase
```

In `couchbase.yaml` the path becomes path: `/couchbase` of course.